# How can I define new init in swift?

Tags: java, swift

I need the code written here, I could not to paste here

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/length-smallest-sub-string-consisting-maximum-distinct-characters/

i need it in swift

Comment: `let count = NO_OF_CHARS`

Comment: What do you mean "I need the code written here"? Do you expect us to convert the code to swift for you because that is not how stackoverflow works. Show us what you have tried and we can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not recommended, But you can define a global constant and use it anywhere you like:

```
// At the top level, outside of any class or etc.
let NO_OF_CHARS = 256
```

Update due to question change:

C style for is deprecated in Swift (since v3 I think), you should convert the syntax to Swift like this:

```
/*
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

}
*/

// Will be like
for i in 0...n {

}
```

Comment: i mean about  count[str.charAt(i)]++

Comment: It's better to tell us what you are going to achieve by showing the input and desired output, and the code you already tried.